# Issue installing lzma-dev on 18.04

Tags: apt, 18.04

After running `sudo apt install lzma-dev`, `pkgconfig` isn't able to find the library. It doesn't seem to have installed the lib files.

Any idea how to resolve this? Thanks!

```
$ dpkg -L lzma-dev
/.
/usr
/usr/include
/usr/include/lzma
/usr/include/lzma/7zVersion.h
/usr/include/lzma/LzFind.c
/usr/include/lzma/LzFind.h
/usr/include/lzma/LzHash.h
/usr/include/lzma/LzmaDec.c
/usr/include/lzma/LzmaDec.h
/usr/include/lzma/LzmaEnc.c
/usr/include/lzma/LzmaEnc.h
/usr/include/lzma/Types.h
/usr/share
/usr/share/doc
/usr/share/doc/lzma-dev
/usr/share/doc/lzma-dev/7zC.txt.gz
/usr/share/doc/lzma-dev/7zFormat.txt.gz
/usr/share/doc/lzma-dev/Methods.txt
/usr/share/doc/lzma-dev/changelog.Debian.gz
/usr/share/doc/lzma-dev/copyright
/usr/share/doc/lzma-dev/lzma.txt.gz
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems that you are trying to install wrong package.

The corresponding `liblzma.pc` file is contained in [`liblzma-dev` package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=bionic&arch=any&mode=exactfilename&searchon=contents&keywords=liblzma.pc). You can install it with:

```
sudo apt-get install liblzma-dev
```

Comment: pfft..thanks the docs I was reading keep referring to lzma-dev. wonder why lzma-dev even exists...anyways thanks for that!